# Calling from android to a html file

Tags: android, html

In android i have used a `WebView` which is calling other `HTML` file(say one.html) which in turn calling other `HTML` file(say second.html).In `second.html` there is one `javascript` function.I want to call that function and pass some parameter too.These data i want to pass data from activity where `WebView` is present.How can i do that because it is calling `one.html` which in turn calling second.html? Any suggestion please.

**one.html:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></… http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url= image.html" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the "datas" to the query string, like this `one.html?foo=1&bar=2` and pass those data to `second.html` using the same way.

**one.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
// borrowed from http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_=""; 
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}

location.href = "second.html?foo=" + getQuerystring('foo', '') +
  "&bar=" + getQuerystring('bar', '');
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**second.html:**

```
<html>
<!-- whatever -->
</html>
```

But if one is a simple redirection (refresh with timing 0) you should load directly in your `Webview` `second.html` (and pass parameters by the query string)

Note: not tested

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url= image.html" /></head><body></body></html>      Thanks RC. but look at my code.how i am calling? i want to call a function which is in another html file.so i have to pass data from through this html to other html.

Comment: i am calling crystals.html from android activity which in turn is calling function in other html file.how can i do this ?